# Media player for Windows with recommendation system like in Amarok

Tags: windows, software-rec, mp3, amarok

I'm looking for a media player for Windows which supports automatic recommendations like in Amarok, something other than Amarok.

Comment: @Sathia recommendation as in recommendation system, not software-rec.

Answer (score 1):

[iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/features/#genius) has [Genius](http://www.apple.com/itunes/features/#genius), which offers recommendations for your music. It's free, but you need an iTunes account for Genius to work. Also, keep in mind that iTunes is a resource hog.

Comment: +1! I'm adore iTunes. And there is no actual need to buy iPod!

Comment: -1. iTunes is very pretty, but it's a terrible music player that comes bundled with Quicktime that takes over parts of your machine and is almost impossible to reconfigure.

Comment: Gah, was about to say this. +1

Answer (score 0):

http://banshee-project.org/ has the same feature like recommendations from Last.fm. Please note that It will work on linux

Answer (score 0):

[Songbird](http://www.getsongbird.com/) (Firefox-based music player) and Last.fm is a good option. Similar to iTunes really, but with extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Zune Software](http://zune.net/en-US/)?  has a pretty nice Marketplace; requires Windows Live ID.  Recommends music, based on your collection and listening habits...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for similar to Amarok then I'll recommend you mediamonkey... (due to its similar interface like amarok 1.4 )

Here is a link to download the same:
http://www.mediamonkey.com/

More and more you will use MediaMonkey... you will discover it far better than any other players.